# Openshift Tomcat 7 WAR Deploy - Work local but not in openshift

Tags: deployment, tomcat7, openshift, war, vraptor

I created an application in Openshift with Tomcat 7 e PostgreSQL.

And built my application with Vraptor 4, JPA and Gradle.

When I build a war and ran and local tomcat, works well. So when i deploy in openshift, doesn't work. Seems don't read .class files and index.html is open, instead of login jsp.

I try find where app is deployed to compare structure, but i didn't.

Thinking out that problem could be the Gradle build, i push the war through SFTP e has the same problem

What i'm doing wrong or forgetting? Where can i look do find out the problem?

Follow the structure of war

```
- .sass-cache
- css
- font
- images
- js
- META-INF
----- MANIFEST.MF
- WEB-INF
----- classes
----------- br (and others packages and class files)
----------- META-INF
---------------- beans.xml
---------------- log4j.xml
---------------- persistence.xml
---------------- validation.xml
---------------- ValidationMessages.properties
----------- development.properties
----------- environment.proporties
----------- logback.xml
----------- messages.properties
----------- production.properties
----- jsp
----- libs
----- web.xml
- index.html
```

**EDIT:** As requested follow my logs.

My Jenkins Log

```
Startedding remotely on librarybldr (library-build) in workspace /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/repo
Checkout:repo / /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/repo - hudson.remoting.Channel@17bd581:librarybldr
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision e38eb58e23605eebd6d10218a38d40b2a71189cf (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checkout:repo / /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/repo - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1f2cd7f
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
Fetching upstream changes from [mygitrepo]
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Commencing build of Revision e38eb58e23605eebd6d10218a38d40b2a71189cf (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checking out Revision e38eb58e23605eebd6d10218a38d40b2a71189cf (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
[repo] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6919511635576326381.sh
+ source /usr/lib/openshift/cartridge_sdk/bash/sdk
++ '[' false == true ']'
++ OO_BASH_SDK=true
+ alias 'rsync=rsync --delete-after -azS -e '\''/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh'\'''
+ upstream_ssh=56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8@library-bukaholic.rhcloud.com
+ rm -f /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c//app-deployments/current/metadata.json
+ marker_present force_clean_build
+ '[' -f /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/markers/force_clean_build ']'
+ set +e
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh '56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8@app-domain.rhcloud.com:$OPENSHIFT_BUILD_DEPENDENCIES_DIR' /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/
Warning: Permanently added 'app-domain.rhcloud.com,172.16.11.161' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh '56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8@library-bukaholic.rhcloud.com:$OPENSHIFT_DEPENDENCIES_DIR' /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/
Warning: Permanently added 'app-domain.rhcloud.com,172.16.11.161' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ set -e
+ gear build
Building git ref 'origin/HEAD', commit e38eb58
+ '[' '!' -d /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/data//gradle-2.11 ']'
+ cd /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/data/
+ mkdir gradle
+ wget http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-bin.zip
DOWNLOAD GRADLE
Skipping Maven build due to absence of pom.xml
+ cd /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/repo/
+ export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/data//gradle
+ GRADLE_USER_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/data//gradle
+ export GRADLE_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/data//gradle-2.11
+ GRADLE_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/data//gradle-2.11
+ export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
+ JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
+ export PATH=/var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/data//gradle-2.11/bin:/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.7.0/bin:/etc/alternatives/maven-3.0/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
+ PATH=/var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/data//gradle-2.11/bin:/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.7.0/bin:/etc/alternatives/maven-3.0/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
+ gradle clean build
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava
Download dependencies

Some error of encode like below

/var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/repo/src/br/com/bukaholic/library/annotation/Public.java:12: error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
 * Anota????o para informar ao {@link AuthenticationInterceptor} que o m??todo
        ^

:processResources
:classes
:war
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 47.952 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.11/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
+ /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh 56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8@library-bukaholic.rhcloud.com 'gear stop --conditional --exclude-web-proxy --git-ref e38eb58e23605eebd6d10218a38d40b2a71189cf'
Warning: Permanently added 'app-domain.rhcloud.com,172.16.11.161' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Stopping gear...
Stopping jbossews cartridge
Sending SIGTERM to jboss:158286 ...
Stopping Postgres cartridge
++ /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh 56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8@app-domain.rhcloud.com 'gear create-deployment-dir'
Warning: Permanently added 'app-domain.rhcloud.com,172.16.11.161' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ deployment_dir=2016-02-24_23-06-33.187
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c//app-deployments/current/metadata.json 56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8@app-domain.rhcloud.com:app-deployments/2016-02-24_23-06-33.187/metadata.json
Warning: Permanently added 'app-domain.rhcloud.com,172.16.11.161' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh --exclude .git /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/repo/ 56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8@app-domain.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/repo/
Warning: Permanently added 'app-domain.rhcloud.com,172.16.11.161' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/ 56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8@app-domain.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/
Warning: Permanently added 'app-domain.rhcloud.com,172.16.11.161' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh /var/lib/openshift/56ce7d537628e1937000006c/app-root/runtime/dependencies/ 56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8@app-domain.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/dependencies/
Warning: Permanently added 'app-domain.rhcloud.com,172.16.11.161' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh 56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8@app-domain.rhcloud.com 'gear remotedeploy --deployment-datetime 2016-02-24_23-06-33.187'
Warning: Permanently added 'app-domain.rhcloud.com,172.16.11.161' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Preparing build for deployment
Deployment id is 4619e5f7
Activating deployment
Starting Postgres cartridge
Postgres started
Starting jbossews cartridge
Found 127.7.73.129:8080 listening port
Archiving artifacts
Finish by user Jenkins Admin
Builed: SUCCESS
```

And this jbossews.log

```
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.7.73.129-8080"]
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.7.73.129-8080"]
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:29 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.7.73.129-8080"]
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina addClusterRuleSet
INFO: Cluster RuleSet not found due to [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterRuleSet]. Cluster configuration disabled.
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/rh/postgresql92/root/usr/lib64:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.7.73.129-8080"]
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1771 ms
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:50 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/openshift/56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:50 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/openshift/56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Feb 24, 2016 11:06:50 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Registering bundled converters
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Registering bundled converters
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.util.Calendar. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.CalendarConverter to class java.util.Calendar
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for double. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.PrimitiveDoubleConverter to double
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.lang.Integer. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.IntegerConverter to class java.lang.Integer
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Found interceptor for class br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.lang.Byte. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.ByteConverter to class java.lang.Byte
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for short. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.PrimitiveShortConverter to short
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.lang.Short. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.ShortConverter to class java.lang.Short
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for float. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.PrimitiveFloatConverter to float
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.lang.Float. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.FloatConverter to class java.lang.Float
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.lang.Character. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.CharacterConverter to class java.lang.Character
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.lang.Enum. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.EnumConverter to class java.lang.Enum
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.math.BigInteger. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.BigIntegerConverter to class java.math.BigInteger
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for interface br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.upload.UploadedFile. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.upload.UploadedFileConverter to interface br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.upload.UploadedFile
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for boolean. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.PrimitiveBooleanConverter to boolean
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.math.BigDecimal. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.BigDecimalConverter to class java.math.BigDecimal
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.util.Date. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.DateConverter to class java.util.Date
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.lang.Long. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.LongConverter to class java.lang.Long
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for byte. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.PrimitiveByteConverter to byte
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for char. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.PrimitiveCharConverter to char
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Found interceptor for class br.com.caelum.vraptor.jpa.JPATransactionInterceptor
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for int. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.PrimitiveIntConverter to int
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.lang.Boolean. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.BooleanConverter to class java.lang.Boolean
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.lang.Double. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.DoubleConverter to class java.lang.Double
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for long. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.PrimitiveLongConverter to long
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Found interceptor for class br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] Unable to find a converter for class java.lang.String. Returning NullConverter.
[24/02/2016 23:07:20] adding converter class br.com.caelum.vraptor.converter.StringConverter to class java.lang.String
[24/02/2016 23:07:21] Caching br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor 
[24/02/2016 23:07:21] Caching br.com.caelum.vraptor.jpa.JPATransactionInterceptor 
[24/02/2016 23:07:21] Caching br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor 
[24/02/2016 23:07:21] VRaptor 4.1.4 successfuly initialized
Feb 24, 2016 11:07:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/56cc6da77628e117cd0001a8/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 32,717 ms
Feb 24, 2016 11:07:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.7.73.129-8080"]
Feb 24, 2016 11:07:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 33608 ms
[24/02/2016 23:10:21] VRaptor received a new request org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5b8ed5
[24/02/2016 23:10:21] trying to access /
[24/02/2016 23:10:21] VRaptor ended the request
[24/02/2016 23:10:21] VRaptor received a new request org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@d667eb
[24/02/2016 23:10:21] trying to access /
[24/02/2016 23:10:21] VRaptor ended the request
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot by viewing your log files (https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html) using rhc tail or by sshing into your application and checking in the ~/app-root/logs directory.

You might want to read through this page (https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-deployment-options.html) of the Developer Portal which describes how to deploy a pre-compiled WAR file to your Tomcat 7 server on OpenShift Online.

If you can get some of the log files and post them here it will be more likely that someone can help you get your application working.  It's possible that some dependency is missing that you have installed locally.